# How to install and configure git on a shared hosting?

Tags: git, ssh, shared-hosting

So I've been searching all over the web on how to install git on my shared host but I still do not have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Get The latest vesion of git from following location 
**https://github.com/git/git/releases**

Logged into your hosting and in your home folder, run the following commands..

> ```
> curl -O http://github.com/git/git/archive/v1.8.3.3.tar.gz(put the latest vesion of git)
> tar zxvf git-1.8.3.3.tar.gz
> cd git-1.8.3.3
> ./configure --prefix=/home/$USER --with-curl --with-expat
> make -i
> make -i install
> echo 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
> source $HOME/.bashrc
> ```

Then type git version it will give **git version 1.8.3**

Comment: follow up question sir, I've stumbled upon the same answer that you made however my shared host does not seem to have activated the curl command. How can I activate it? Thanks!